# Как реализовать вывод фотографий через JSON запрос к серверу?

Tags: java, android

Требуется реализовать возможность вывода фотографий после получения ответа JSON с сервера. В этом ответе содержаться прямые ссылки на фотографии. То есть идет запрос к серверу -> получения ответа JSON -> вывод фото на экран смартфона. Подскажите, как такое реализовать? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону библиотек

- Retrofit для получения JSON и его разбора
- Glide для подгрузки и кэщирования картинок на место ImageView

  ```
  callToday.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherDay>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<WeatherDay> call, Response<WeatherDay> response) {
          Log.e(TAG, "onResponse");
          WeatherDay data = response.body();
          //Log.d(TAG,response.toString());

          if (response.isSuccessful()) {
              tvTemp.setText(data.getCity() + " " + data.getTempWithDegree());
              Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(data.getIconUrl()).into(tvImage);
          }
  ```

Код отсюда https://proft.me/2017/05/5/poluchenie-prognoza-pogody-android-retrofit/

Если у вас коллекция, загружайте в RecycleView Adapter и например так отображайте

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
  ImageView imageView = ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).imageView;
  String currentUrl = myUrls.get(position);

  GlideApp.with(fragment)
    .load(currentUrl)
    .override(imageWidthPixels, imageHeightPixels)
    .into(imageView);
}
```

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/recyclerview.html

Answer (score 0):

Если вы получается в ответ от сервера ссылку на фотографию, то вам поможет Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) и Retrofit для работы с JSON ответом